How can I draw triangles within a triangle if I know their perimeters?
I am trying to draw this picture with perimeters of the triangles in a larger triangle. I don't know how to start.


What about starting with writing equations?

Here is a simple example of two triangles with perimeters 5 and 10 that together form a bigger triangle:
scene = GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d},
  {d \[Element] Line[{b, c}], 
  Triangle[{a, b, c}], Triangle[{a, b, d}], Triangle[{a, d, c}], 
  TriangleMeasurement[Triangle[{a, b, d}], "Perimeter"] == 5,
  TriangleMeasurement[Triangle[{a, d, c}], "Perimeter"] == 10
  }
];
RandomInstance[scene]




This can be elaborated on to get your triangle, but it will require you to code up all of the constraints.

Based on my experience with GeometricScene I would be very surprised if this is going to work with OP's triangles.

Maybe, maybe not. But I'm not going to do all of their work for them. I'm just suggesting an approach for them to try. If it doesn't work, we'll see again.
